# How do I set up a baseline test in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

This is what the development manager wants set up:

- 1% Concurrency ~ 20 virtual users
- 90% Contributors for ~ 18 running contributor tasks
- 10% Group Admins ~ 3 running group tasks
- Ramp users at 1 per minute.

Run all 21 users for an hour (after ramp) to see how the system performs.

How do I set this up in Jmeter?   I assume that the users are my thread and ramp at 1 per minute means that I enter 60 seconds.   I would have different thread groups for each of the task types (contributor, manager/admin).   Just not sure how I allow it to run for an hour after the ramp.   Is that with using the scheduler??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There scheduler option for the thread group. You can try this:

[image]

I hope that can help you.